# ssh daemon error: sshd must be own

Tags: sshd

Running `service sshd restart` and then `service sshd status` on my system as root prints the following error:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  status sshd.service sshd.service -
>   OpenSSH server daemon       Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled)     Active: failed
>   (Result: exit-code) since Sat, 16 Feb 2013 21:38:38 +0330; 6s ago
>   Process: 2207 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS (code=exited,
>   status=255)    Process: 2204 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-keygen
>   (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)     CGroup:
>   name=systemd:/system/sshd.service
>
> Feb 16 21:38:38 localhost.localdomain sshd[2207]: /var/empty/sshd must
>   be own...

How do I find the cause of the problem?

Comment: The last (truncated!) line of the error message presumably talks about ownership of `/var/empty/sshd`, here (Fedora 18) I have `drwx--x--x. 2 root root 4096 Feb  8 11:18 /var/empty/sshd/`, that directory is owned by package `openssh-server` (perhaps reinstall that one?).

Comment: Reinstalling openssh-server solved the problem. Thanks. If you want, add it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last (truncated!) line of the error message presumably talks about ownership of `/var/empty/sshd`, here (Fedora 18) `ls -ld` gives:

```
drwx--x--x. 2 root root 4096 Feb 8 11:18 /var/empty/sshd/
```

Running `rpm -qf /var/empty/sshd` gives:

```
openssh-server-6.1p1-5.fc18.x86_64
```

So that directory is owned by package `openssh-server` (perhaps reinstall that one?)

Answer (score -2):

If you use Magento or use command line to change /var/ to 777, it might be you are accidentally change all permissions to that state (777).

> Just connect to virtuozzo / cpanel / whm and change it back to 700 or owner (all checklist) and unchecklist the others